# Unable to Download and install and copy .ovpn file to config location for OpenVpn on MAC

Tags: openvpn

I am trying to download and install OPENVPN for MacBook, but could not find right link for this.
I have done the installation at windows by following link "https://openvpn.net/index.php/download/community-downloads.html"
And there after download I have copied .ovpn file under config folder.
But with MAC, I am really not sure where I can copy my .OVPN file.
I found this link to download for MAC "https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/connecting-to-access-server-with-macos/".
Can someone please share step by step guide for this.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this ?